# Nuget error: Please provide credentials for: https://www.myget.org/F

Tags: nuget, tfsbuild, myget

Nuget keeps telling me dat it cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode. I added the credentials to the nuget.config and added nuget the -NonInteractive switch to the nuget command. I guess i'm doing something wrong... But what?

Part of the build log:

```
RestorePackages:
  C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.exe sources add -name rai69 -source "https://www.myget.com/F/rai69/"
  Package Source with Name: rai69 added successfully.
  C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.exe setapikey 763736d6-ff35-45ca-af37-064cfc87fc45 -source "https://www.myget.com/F/rai69/"
  The API Key '763736d6-ff35-45ca-af37-064cfc87fc45' was saved for 'https://www.myget.com/F/rai69/'.
  C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.exe sources update -name rai69 -user **** -pass ****
  Package source "rai69" was successfully updated.
  attrib -r C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.config
  copy %appdata%\nuget\nuget.config C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget /y
      1 file(s) copied.
  "C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.exe" install "C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\packages.config" -source "https://www.myget.org/F/rai69/" -o "C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\packages" -verbosity detailed -noninteractive 
  Please provide credentials for: https://www.myget.org/F/rai69/
C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.targets(121,7): error : Cannot prompt for input in non-interactive mode.     [C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest.csproj]
  UserName: 
C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.targets(121,7): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\.nuget\nuget.exe" install         "C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\packages.config" -source "https://www.myget.org/F/rai69/" -o "C:\a\src\d\projects\poc\TfsOnlineBuildNugetTest\packages" -verbosity detailed -noninteractive " exited with code 1.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can now properly use a cleartext password in a local nuget.config, as explained in this post: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/deploying-to-azure-web-sites-using-nuget-package-restore-from-a-secured-feed

Also check the nuget.config settings documentation at http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/nuget-config-settings.

Comment: I thought i was doing this in de restorepackage scripts.

Comment: sorry I overlooked that, mea culpa, edited my answer, hope it helps!

Comment: Didn't do the trick. The local nuget.config now looks like:   
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <configuration>
    <solution>
      <add key="disableSourceControlIntegration" value="true" />
    </solution>
   
  </configuration>

Comment: I meant, ensuring there is NO local NuGet.config :)

Comment: Didn't work either. I read back my question and noticed that i didn't explicit mention that i'm using tfs online (tfs.visualstudio.com) build services.

Comment: true, didn't notice it, hope my edits above can point you towards a working solution

Comment: thanx to this change in nuget it works: http://www.xavierdecoster.com/deploying-to-azure-web-sites-using-nuget-package-restore-from-a-secured-feed